# Composer Installer Error : Signature mismatch

Tags: composer-php

i have a error : **Signature mismatch, could not verify the phar file integrity** when install composer on windows OS.

When inspecting the code, I come across the `$signature` variable that does not have a relationship in the `verifyAndSave()` function call. It's normal ?

But, if I comment test with the `verifyAndSave()` function, the installation takes place correctly...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this error during install : **Signature mismatch, could not verify the phar file integrity**

Comment temporarily : `zend_extension=opcache` in your **php.ini**, run Composer install and after, uncomment.

Work with PHP 7.2.0.